# Save variables in every iteration of for loop and load them later

Tags: python, loops, save, load

I want to save the variables `m`, `n`, `r`, `X`, `Y` (see code below) in one file e.g `file_1` and 
repeat for every iteration with a new file name prefarably with 
the iteration number e.g., `file_2`.

In MATLAB I could simply do `save(['data_',int2str(i),'.mat'],'variable1', 'variable2' )` so that `data(1)` will contain `m`, `n`, `r`, `X`, `Y`; `data(2)` will contain `m`, `n`, `r`, `X`, `Y` with their new values, and so on

How do I do same in Python?

```
Test = 5
for i in range(Tests):
    r = 5
    m = 500
    n = 500
    X=np.random.rand(m,n)
    Y=np.random.rand(m,n)
```

Comment: You can save the variables to a file using the `pickle` library

Answer (score 2):

The `pickle` library is the way to go here.

```
import pickle
Tests = 5
data = {}
for i in range(Tests):
    data['r'] = 5
    data['m'] = 500
    data['n'] = 500
    data['X'] = np.random.rand(data['m'],data['n'])
    data['Y'] = np.random.rand(data['m'],data['n'])
    with open('data{}.pickle'.format(i), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
```

This allows you to access your dictionary of data later. For example,

```
with open('data0.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
r = data['r']
m = data['m']
```

and so on.

Comment: How assuming my loop was till 40. can i use a loop to load all 40?

Comment: You can always move the code that loads the pickled data into a for loop, allowing you to load all 40. Just change the name of the file within the for loop, like the above code does in saving the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jwil

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you so more people don't spend time typing their solutions. @Farouk Yahaya

Comment: I tried to implemt it. it underlines the word data. and says 



"Unresolved reference 'data' less... (Ctrl+F1) Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items."

Comment: @Farouk Yahaya This is probably just an issue specific to your IDE, since I can run this script without any issues using interactive python. Is the problem fatal? This sounds like a warning rather than a fatal error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do the same in python.

```
import numpy as np
Test = 2
for i in range(Test):
    r = 5
    m = 500
    n = 500
    X=np.random.rand(m,n)
    Y=np.random.rand(m,n)
    file_name = 'test_'+str(i)
    open(file_name,'w').write(str(r) + str(m) + str(n) + str(X) + str(Y))
```

Comment: why will you cast them to str. they are real values. X and Y are matrix. Im new to python btw.

Comment: If you don't cast it, it will throw error - TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray

Comment: So can u please tell me how to load it. and if i do load it, will i get them back in their original format? i.e scalars and matrices and not as strings?

Comment: If you want to preserve the properties of the object such as the data type and all, then prefer using pickle() to save the data and it as an object.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sanchit

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it without using any libraries here's my solution:

```
import numpy as np
Test = 5
for i in range(Test):
    r = 5
    m = 500
    n = 500
    X=np.random.rand(m,n)
    Y=np.random.rand(m,n)

    file = open('file_{}'.format(i+1), 'w')
    file.write('r = {};m = {};n = {};X = {};Y = {}'.format(r, m, n, X, Y))
    file.close()
```

Loading saved variables

```
exec(open('file_1', 'r').read())
```

Comment: this looks simple for small range. my loop will go from 1 to 40. when loading exucuting them one by one can be annoyning.